# print long character values with line break in r markdown table (to latex pdf)

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I'm using R markdown and latex to write some reports and I'd like to print a table with variables that take long character values. The values are so long that the table doesn't fit the page. If I were to work in latex directly I would just manualy add `\\` to insert a line break but I don't know how to do that in markdown since I don't see the latex code in the chunks.

Minimal working example:

````
```{r}
x<-c("Some looooong value that should be way shorter", "another value", "not sure if the other value was long enough to show my point")

x<- table(data.frame(x))
```
````

I get

```
x
                                               another value 
                                                           1 
not sure if the other value was long enough to show my point 
                                                           1 
              Some looooong value that should be way shorter 
                                                           1
```

But I'd rather have

```
x
                                               another value 
                                                           1 
                             not sure if the other value was 
                                long enough to show my point 
                                                           1 
                             Some looooong value that should 
                                              be way shorter 
                                                           1
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

So, I answered my own question:
You can set the column width using

```
column_spec(table, column index, width)
```

assuming "table" is the table you already generated but need to modify. This will set the column width and break the lines accordingly.